# Reduce the code using a method

Tags: ios, swift

Hello there I'm doing the Udacity nanodegree, I'm working with textFields, but I need to reduce the code using a method that takes UITextField as parameter.
I actually I don't know what the method could be, and I don't have any idea how to reduce the code.
I will let you the code that and hope you can help me

```
let memeTextAttributes = [
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor(), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor(), NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!, NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -1.0]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    topText.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
    bottomText.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
    topText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    bottomText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    shareButton.enabled = false
```

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
func configTextField(defaultText: String, textField: UITextField)
{
    textField.text = defaultText
    textField.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .AllCharacters
    textField.textAlignment = .Center
    textField.delegate = self

}
```

Since it is a meme you can automatically capitalize the whole text.
Then call the above function in `viewDidLoad`. 
For example, the bottom textField will be called in `viewDidLoad` by:

```
configTextField("BOTTOM", textField: bottomTextField)
```